# Background image not showing up in css

Tags: css, background

I have looked through the site, and tried multiple things that other people said worked, but my image is still not working, the text color is working fine, so it doesnt seem to be a error when using the external CSS. here is my css. I have used the https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ to validate the text, and it seems to be correct, but for some reason it is not showing up.

```
      body { 
  background-image:url('images/sg.jpg');
  color:#BFB083;
  }
  h1{ color:#BFB083;}
  a{color: #705438}

  #wrapper { width: 1000px;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
              }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct and the image exists? Check the browser's console for errors.

Comment: If the HTML is in `/directory/` and the css is in `/directory/css/` and the images in `/directory/images/`, the path ro the images from the css needs to be `../images/`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash to the beginning of the background url:

```
background-image:url('/images/sg.jpg');
```